# Multiple checkbox buttons in swift 3

Tags: swift

I have working code for a checkbox in swift, but the project I'm looking to build has about 50 or so checkboxes. In keeping with the goal of less code is best I'm wondering if there's a better way to write it all out than to just copy and paste. I tried linking multiple buttons to one iboutlet but I guess that was not the way to go seeing as how a different button would register selected then the one tapped.

working code:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!

var isButtonClicked: Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isButtonClicked = false
}

@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if isButtonClicked == true {
        isButtonClicked = false
    }
    else {
        isButtonClicked = true
    }

    if isButtonClicked == true {
        buttonOne.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonClicked"), for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        buttonOne.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonUnclicked"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use tableView with your checkbox label.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your checkboxes?

Comment: You could assign tags to the buttons and access them with `viewWithTag...` which could be used as an index. By the way, the `sender` parameter of the `IBAction` is the afftected button, so you could use one `IBAction` and get the state with `sender.state` and set the image with `sender.setImage...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a class for the checkboxes. Example:

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
    var checked = false {
        didSet {
            if checked == true {
                self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonClicked"), for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonUnclicked"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func tapped() {
        self.checked = !self.checked
        if checked == true {
            self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonClicked"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            self.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ButtonUnclicked"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use this class to create checkboxes programmatically using a for loop. Example:

```
for i in 0..<50 {
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: i * 40, width: 40, height: 40))
    checkbox.tag = 1
    self.someView.addSubview(checkbox)
}
```